# $A$ is similar to $Diag(a_1,...,a_n)$. Then the sum of elements in A's diagonal is $a_1+...+a_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $D=Diag(a_1,...,a_n)$ denote the diagonal matrix with diagonal $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. I noticed that if $A$ and $D$ are similar marices, then the sum of elements in $A$'s diagonal is also $a_1+...+a_n$. 
 I could not find a counter example, and I'm not sure how to prove it. Is it always true? If so, I would love to see a proof using only the fact that there exists $P$ such that $A=P^{-1} \cdot D \cdot P$,if there is one, because that's all I know about similar matrices right now. Thank you!

Comment: The sum of the diagonal is called trace. It satisfies $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ , just calculate. Therefore the trace of similar matrices are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix is called the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of a matrix. Use the decomposition $A = P^{-1} D P$ as well as the following property of trace:

> $$\text{tr}(M_1 M_2 M_3) = \text{tr}(M_2 M_3 M_1).$$

Comment: To prove the mentioned property you only need the simpler $\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: @angryavian Nice, thanks. The proof of that property is just as technical as multiply those matrices and see the diagonal sum is the same?

Comment: @Omer Yes, you can prove it directly in that manner. And as others mentioned, it suffices to just deal with the product of two matrices.